# Secondary expansion in make prereqs with patsubst

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following make file:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
CXX         = g++
CXXFLAGS    = -Wall -W -ansi -I. -I../Include
BUILD_DIR   = obj    
OUT = bin/EngineTests
SRC = LiveTestReporterStdout.cpp \
    EngineTests.cpp \
    IntegratorValidationTest.cpp \
PRIVATE_SRC = Private/Unit/BlockTests/AlertBlockTest.cpp \
    Private/Unit/BlockTests/CapBlockTest.cpp \
    Private/TestHelpers.cpp

OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))

all: $(OUT)

private: SRC += $(PRIVATE_SRC)
private: $(OUT)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    @echo $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $<
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OUT): $(OBJS)
    @echo Linking $@ ...
    # blah
```

The goal being able to do `make` to build `all` from just `$(SRC)` and `make private` to build from `$(SRC) + $(PRIVATE_SRC)`.  But it doesnt work - I'm aware that target specific variables cant be used for pre-reqs and the solution somehow involves secondary expansion, but cant get it to work.

I have tried `OBJS = $$(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $$(SRC))` and various things like that.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you need to specify the source files themselves? Why not just say `OBJS := LiveTestReporterStdout.o ...`, PRIVATE_OBJS := `Private/Unit/BlockTests/AlertBlockTest.o ...`, `private: OBJS += $(PRIVATE_OBJS)`? Try explaining in more detail what you want to achieve as there may be a better way.

Comment: You have to put the secondary expansion into the _prerequisite list_, not into the variable value.  E.g., you want: `$(OUT): $$(OBJS)` not `$(OUT): $(OBJS)`